# Data tables form submit all records

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, datatable

I am using Jquery datatables to display all employees details in form, When I submit the form it post only first page form values. But I need to post all the form values

Here is my code

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery('#emptable').dataTable();
 
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" type="text/css"  />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<form name="emp" method="post">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="stdtable" id="emptable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="head0">S.No</th>
        <th class="head1">Name</th>
        <th class="head0">Dep Name</th>
        <th class="head1">Comments</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
    <td>1<input type='hidden' name='serialno' value='1'></td>
    <td>xyz<input type='hidden' name='name[]' value='xyz'></td>
    <td>DE<input type='hidden' name='dep[]' value='DE'></td>
    <td><textarea name="comments[]"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>2<input type='hidden' name='serialno' value='2'></td>
    <td>abc<input type='hidden' name='name[]' value='xyz'></td>
    <td>DED<input type='hidden' name='dep[]' value='DED'></td>
    <td><textarea name="comments[]"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>3<input type='hidden' name='serialno' value='3'></td>
    <td>adc<input type='hidden' name='name[]' value='adc'></td>
    <td>EDE<input type='hidden' name='dep[]' value='EDE'></td>
    <td><textarea name="comments[]"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Like all 'N' records will display here -->
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</table> 
</form>
```

Here is My form submission code

```
<?php 
include_once("includes/dbConnect.inc.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$serialno=$_POST['serialno'];
for($i=0; $i< $serialno;)
{
$name=$_POST['name'][$i];
$dep=$_POST['dep'][$i];
$comments=$_POST['comments'][$i];
$query=mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO xyz(......remaining code )");
$i++;
}
if($query){echo "Inserted";}
else{echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));}
}
?>
```

When I run this code and submit the form, Only first page values(First 10 row records) are inserting in to DB. But I need to insert all the table records into DB, Can any one please help me, How do I achieve this.

Comment: You only show 10 items per page. Changes in architecture is needed or you have to submit each page then move to another

Comment: Is there any possibility submit form after entered all comments.

Comment: @Angel you can increase the records limit for the page.

Comment: @AmitRajput No, Actually we have almost 1000 records

Comment: Hmm..It will not be suitable.

Comment: what are serialno fields in input form?

Comment: No one here to help me..

Comment: @Angel check my posted answer and tell me if it is helpful to you and solve your problem.

Comment: Guys Please suggest me..... It's eating my time.........

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This is the working correct solution.

Html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" type="text/css"  />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<form id="formID" name="emp" method="post">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="stdtable" id="emptable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="head0">S.No</th>
        <th class="head1">Name</th>
        <th class="head0">Dep Name</th>
        <th class="head1">Comments</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
    <td>1<input type='hidden' name='serialno[]' value='1'></td>
    <td>xyz<input type='hidden' name='name[]' value='name1'></td>
    <td>DE<input type='hidden' name='dep[]' value='dep1'></td>
    <td><textarea name="comments[]"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>2<input type='hidden' name='serialno[]' value='2'></td>
    <td>abc<input type='hidden' name='name[]' value='name2'></td>
    <td>DED<input type='hidden' name='dep[]' value='dep2'></td>
    <td><textarea name="comments[]"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>3<input type='hidden' name='serialno[]' value='3'></td>
    <td>adc<input type='hidden' name='name[]' value='name3'></td>
    <td>EDE<input type='hidden' name='dep[]' value='dep3'></td>
    <td><textarea name="comments[]"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>3<input type='hidden' name='serialno[]' value='4'></td>
    <td>adc<input type='hidden' name='name[]' value='name4'></td>
    <td>EDE<input type='hidden' name='dep[]' value='dep4'></td>
    <td><textarea name="comments[]"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>3<input type='hidden' name='serialno[]' value='5'></td>
    <td>adc<input type='hidden' name='name[]' value='name5'></td>
    <td>EDE<input type='hidden' name='dep[]' value='dep5'></td>
    <td><textarea name="comments[]"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>3<input type='hidden' name='serialno[]' value='6'></td>
    <td>adc<input type='hidden' name='name[]' value='name6'></td>
    <td>EDE<input type='hidden' name='dep[]' value='dep6'></td>
    <td><textarea name="comments[]"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>3<input type='hidden' name='serialno[]' value='7'></td>
    <td>adc<input type='hidden' name='name[]' value='name7'></td>
    <td>EDE<input type='hidden' name='dep[]' value='dep7'></td>
    <td><textarea name="comments[]"></textarea></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td>3<input type='hidden' name='serialno[]' value='8'></td>
    <td>adc<input type='hidden' name='name[]' value='name8'></td>
    <td>EDE<input type='hidden' name='dep[]' value='dep8'></td>
    <td><textarea name="comments[]"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>3<input type='hidden' name='serialno[]' value='9'></td>
    <td>adc<input type='hidden' name='name[]' value='name9'></td>
    <td>EDE<input type='hidden' name='dep[]' value='dep9'></td>
    <td><textarea name="comments[]"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>3<input type='hidden' name='serialno[]' value='10'></td>
    <td>adc<input type='hidden' name='name[]' value='name10'></td>
    <td>EDE<input type='hidden' name='dep[]' value='dep10'></td>
    <td><textarea name="comments[]"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>3<input type='hidden' name='serialno[]' value='11'></td>
    <td>adc<input type='hidden' name='name[]' value='name11'></td>
    <td>EDE<input type='hidden' name='dep[]' value='dep11'></td>
    <td><textarea name="comments[]"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>3<input type='hidden' name='serialno[]' value='12'></td>
    <td>adc<input type='hidden' name='name[]' value='name12'></td>
    <td>EDE<input type='hidden' name='dep[]' value='dep11'></td>
    <td><textarea name="comments[]"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Like all 'N' records will display here -->
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</table> 
</form>
```

JavaScript :

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var oTable = jQuery('#emptable').dataTable();

        $( "#formID" ).submit(function( event ) {           
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "post.php",                
                data: oTable.$('input, textarea').serialize(),
                success: function(response){
                   alert(response);
                }
            });
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevents default form submit
        });    
    });
</script>
```

PHP (post.php) :

```
<?php 

    echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); 

?>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for your time, But it doesn't works, showing blank alert box

Comment: No, its working at my end. You are something doing wrong. Just replace with my code then check again or create a demo for testing.

Comment: I didn't even change a single bit of your code, But it gives me a blank alert box

Comment: OK...I got it. There was the if condition in post.php file. I have updated. Just replace post.php file code as I have updated. Then check and tell me if it is working or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <?php 
    include_once("includes/dbConnect.inc.php");
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  //  $serialno=$_POST['serialno'];
    for($i=0; $i< 1000)
    {
    $name=$_POST['name'][$i];
    $dep=$_POST['dep'][$i];
    $comments=$_POST['comments'][$i];
    $query=mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO xyz(......remaining code )");
    $i++;
    }
    if($query){echo "Inserted";}
    else{echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));}
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: No it's not working because, It's inserting form data of first 10 records after that it's going to insert null values

Comment: I would suggest you to display record on calling page prior to insert into database for testing.

Comment: whats value $serialno is in php file?

Comment: It's a count of records, Actually I am displaying employees details from DB so $serialno is a row count number

Comment: In your post, you said there is less record insertion issue into db.